# How can I change the text "image 1 or ? '

Tags: css

How can I change the text "image 1 or 5 ' (in Dutch) or delete it. I use Lightbox-plus-jquery.js in Ligtbox2. I can’t find it in JS or CSS.

Excuse my English ...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review [**How to ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) questions on Stack Overflow and what types of questions [**can be asked**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and what types [**should be avoided.**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: it is better to accompany your questions with the code you've written even if wrong. As said in the previous comment, in order to find more quickly the answers you need, there are rules that must be followed

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it myself. In the rule ' AlwaysShowNavOnTouchDevices changed to Dutch: 'Figure 1% of 2% ' to ‘afbeelding 1% van 2%’.